# Python create nested dictionary from list

Tags: python

I query DB to get list of products which I then want to transform to a dict. 
That's my model:

```
class Product(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'products'

    id = db.Column(db.Unicode(64), primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.Unicode(2048), nullable=False)
    descripton = db.Column(db.Unicode(2048), nullable=False)
```

That's what I want as result:

```
result = { id: { name: name, description: description}, ... }
```

Can I use list comprehension syntax to do this?

```
result = {p.id: {name: p.name, description: p.description for p in products.all()}
```

Comment: not much use here but ndb has a to_dict method: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/modelclass#Model_to_dict

Comment: Have you actually tried running your code? Does it return an error? (yes, you did not fully close your dict comprehension, you're missing a bracket, but aside from that - any problems?).

Comment: no I didn't. I'm new to python and googling for answers I didn't see this construction. I wrote it on fly to demonstrate what I want achieve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can. Take this:

```
{p.id: {name: p.name, description: p.description}  for p in products.all()}
```

But are you sure that you need it? You can override `__getitem__` method:

```
class Product(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'products'

    id = db.Column(db.Unicode(64), primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.Unicode(2048), nullable=False)
    descripton = db.Column(db.Unicode(2048), nullable=False)

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        # Code to find object in DB and transform them if you want.
```